# How to find match between two 2D lists in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, list

Lets say I have two 2D lists like this:

```
list1 = [ ['A', 5], ['X', 7], ['P', 3]]
list2 = [ ['B', 9], ['C', 5], ['A', 3]]
```

I want to compare these two lists and find where the 2nd item matches between the two lists e.g here we can see that numbers 5 and 3 appear in both lists. The first item is actually not relevant in comparison.

How do I compare the lists and copy those values that appear in 2nd column of both lists? Using 'x in list' does not work since these are 2D lists. Do I create another copy of the lists with just the 2nd column copied across?

It is possible that this can be done using list comprehension but I am not sure about it so far.

There might be a duplicate for this but I have not found it yet.

Comment: There's really not that much to it. When you do `for x in list1`, each `x` will be a list. I'm sure you know how to access the second element of `x`. Give it a shot, [edit] your attempt into the question, and if you have a _specific_ problem with your code, ask about that problem!

Comment: You could create some `set`s like `set1 = set(i[1] for i in list1)` and `set2 = set(i[1] for i in list2)`. and then create a `list` by checking membership `[i for i in set1 if i in set2]`.

Comment: I am literally writing my very first serious Python script, so far I only worked through textbook examples

Comment: When I was first learning programming and then Python, I found it much more helpful to make mistakes and understand what I was doing wrong than to look online for a readymade answer. Trust me, it's much better this way -- Nobody writes perfect code on their first try (even after decades of experience), and learning how to find and fix your mistakes is just as (if not more) important as knowing how to write the code in the first place. If you have questions about your attempt, we're here to help :)

Comment: I found the solution: file_list_duplicates = [x[1] for x in file_list_other for y in file_list_this if x[1]==y[1]]

Comment: What if either list has duplicate numbers?

Comment: If a list has duplicates within itself, this shall not be detected. You are right, I must look for this as well. But this will be done separately.

Comment: what is the desired output? 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pursuit of one-liners is a futile exercise. They aren't always more efficient than the regular loopy way, and almost always less readable when you're writing anything more complicated than one or two nested loops. So let's get a multi-line solution first. Once we have a working solution, we can try to convert it to a one-liner.

Now the solution you shared in the comments *works*, but it doesn't handle duplicate elements and also is `O(n^2)` because it contains a nested loop. https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

```
list_common = [x[1] for x in list1 for y in list2 if x[1] == y[1]]
```

A few key things to remember:

- A single loop `O(n)` is better than a nested loop `O(n^2)`.
- Membership lookup in a `set` `O(1)` is *much quicker* than lookup in a list `O(n)`.
- Sets also get rid of duplicates for you.
- Python includes `set` operations like union, intersection, etc.

Let's code something using these points:

```
# Create a set containing all numbers from list1
set1 = set(x[1] for x in list1)

# Create a set containing all numbers from list2
set2 = set(x[1] for x in list2)

# Intersection contains numbers in both sets
intersection = set1.intersection(set2)

# If you want, convert this to a list
list_common = list(intersection)
```

Now, to convert this to a one-liner:

```
list_common = list(set(x[1] for x in list1).intersection(x[1] for x in list2))
```

We don't need to explicitly convert `x[1] for x in list2` to a set because the `set.intersection()` function takes generator expressions and internally handles the conversion to a set.

This gives you the result in `O(n)` time, and also gets rid of duplicates in the process.